# Replacing empty row with string

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a hard time finding a simple solution to an empty mysql query. What I want, is for a row that's retrieved and empty, to be replaced with 'no-image.png' by default. How would I go about that if my code looks like this?

```
$query="SELECT
venues.*
LEFT JOIN events 
ON events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID  
where events.VENUE_LOCATION IS NULL
ORDER BY VENUE_NAME";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<td><IMG src=\"" . $row['IMAGE_URL'] . "\"></td>";
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use conditionals in PHP (i.e `if`)?

Comment: It is extremely odd to me that you can connect to a database, use a `while` condition, etc. but haven't bother to learn one of the most basic control structures in the language.  Like you went directly to chapter 8 in whatever manual you are following and skipped right through chapters 1-7.  Take a look at this:  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php  Also beware that wherever you are getting instruction from is outdated as you should not be using `mysql_*` functions anymore.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions as of `PHP 5.5.0` are deprecated. Use something like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
echo "<td><IMG src=\"" . ($row['IMAGE_URL']?$row['IMAGE_URL']:'no-image.png') . "\"></td>";
```

or you can use if/else construct

```
if ($row['IMAGE_URL'] !== ''){
    $img = $row['IMAGE_URL'];
}
else{
    $img = 'no-image.png';
}
echo "<td><IMG src=\"" . $img . "\"></td>";
```

Comment: might want to do `!empty($row['IMAGE_URL'])?...`

Comment: The ternary operator is fine and dandy, but you may want to show the more verbose `if {} else {}` construct here as the OP doesn't even have a grasp of that notation much less the ternary shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the variable before outputting it, for example:

```
if(!empty($row['IMAGE_URL']))
  $img = $row['IMAGE_URL'];
else
 $img = 'no-image.png';

    echo "<td><IMG src=\"" .$img. "\"></td>";
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF`

Comment: Yeah, should have reviewed the code. Fixed now tho.